# Inserting data into a SQL server table, while adding 30 days to a date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do:

I am building an inventory system for availability for a class project. I am trying to load all a set of default data (comprised of Equipment ID and how many are available when none are out) and change the date to keep an ongoing database that tracks availability at any time within the next 30 days.

How I'm trying to do it:

My professor (who is pretty hands-off) enabled access to SQL Job Agent in SQL Management Studio and I am currently building a statement that allows me to copy all the default data mentioned about and re-add that to the database but add 30 days to the date column. I want to get this statement to work first before making it a procedure

What I have:

```
insert into EquipmentAvailabilities(Date, NumberAvailable, EquipmentId)
values((GETDATE()+30), 
(select NumberAvailable, EquipmentId from EquipmentAvailabilities));
```

What SMS is giving me:

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
Msg 109, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
```

What I've tried: I've only tried the following after figuring out how to GETDATE.

```
insert into EquipmentAvailabilities(Date, NumberAvailable, EquipmentId)
values((GETDATE()+30), 
(select NumberAvailable from EquipmentAvailabilities), 
(select  EquipmentId from EquipmentAvailabilities));
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: `insert into t (c1, c2, c3) select ... `

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing stuff up in your query here. And don't use shortcuts for date math.

```
insert into EquipmentAvailabilities
(
    Date
    , NumberAvailable
    , EquipmentId
)
select dateadd(day, 30, getdate())
    , NumberAvailable
    , EquipmentId 
from EquipmentAvailabilities
```

Comment: This is taking all entries and duplicating them, I need to narrow it down to just the default values for each equipment. As it is now, if I have 58 entries, run that command itll have 116. If I run it again, itll have 232. How can I restrict it to only the 58(of however may pieces)?

Comment: With a where clause?

Comment: To only chose unique EquipmentIds? I tried a where equipmentId = unique, but its not recognizing. I'm not sure how to select only the equipmentId that should be default

Comment: I don't know either because I have no idea what your table structure is. Maybe you have a column for IsDefault? Maybe you want the earliest date for each EquipmentID? And of course where equipmentId = unique isn't going to work because that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 30 days to the *date* column, then don't use `getdate()`:

```
insert into EquipmentAvailabilities (Date, NumberAvailable, EquipmentId)
    select dateadd(day, 30, date),
           NumberAvailable, EquipmentId
    from EquipmentAvailabilities;
```